# How to create thumbnail from original image without distortion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using **cropper.js** library to crop a image. Based on the cropped image, a thumbnail is created by passing height and width as below,

```
cropper.getCroppedCanvas({ width: 100, height: 100 })
```

But the output thumbnail image is distorted. The memory size of the thumbnail image should not cross more than 5kb. For example: stack overflow user icon, facebook chat window user icon.

Comment: are you talking about `resize` image?

Comment: @JaredChu I am cropping large image using cropper.js library and trying to created thumbnail(user icon) out of it with 100x100 dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You should set canvas data first. If not, the canvas data will be equal your whole image size and it will be distorted after crop.

```
cropper.setCanvasData({ left:0,top:0, width: 100, height: 100 })
cropper.getCroppedCanvas({ width: 100, height: 100 })
```